# Gvim ctags Ctrl-] stops working after some time

Tags: vim, ctags

I have setup Gvim to work with Ctags and Cscope. When I do a tag search using Ctrl-] it works for a while, and after some time it stops working for the same tags that were resolved earlier (even though there were no code changes). Does not show any errors. However, Ctrl-T, :ta , cscope command line commands work fine. Just the Ctrl-] stops working. Only way I am able to get it work again is to close down the Gvim window and reopen the file again. Problem repeats after a while.

Any insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the other tags commands are still working, this sounds like some plugin overrides the key mapping. Next time this happens, investigate via

```
:verbose nmap <C-]>
```

To verify that the key combination still works, you could try

```
:nnoremap <C-]> :echomsg "Ctrl + ] works!"<CR>
```

Comment: Even when the mapping works, the verbose command says 'no such mapping found'. I tried the command you suggested as well as :verbose map <C-]>.

Comment: No, use this when the command _breaks down_; normally, there shouldn't be a mapping.

Comment: Yes, I tried it when it breaks down as well, and it says the same thing that there is no mapping. It does print the message 'Ctrl + ] works!' though.

Comment: So, the key combination still works, but the (apparently unmapped) built-in command stops working. If that's right, you could work around the issue with this map: `:nnoremap <C-]> :tag <C-r>%<CR>`

Comment: Weirdly enough today when I encountered the issue, the key combination itself didn't seem to work since the echomsg did not get displayed and the proposed workaround didn't help either.